# Modified Dominos Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, permutation, matching

I'm trying to solve a slight variation of dominos, in which you're given a set of domino tiles, and must order them such that the number of *mismatches* (when two adjacent tiles don't have the same touching number, e.g. `[1 | 3] [4 | 1]` = mismatch) is minimised. Additionally, tiles cannot be rotated, only transformed (e.g. [1 | 3] cannot be rotated to [3 | 1]), and

For example, say you're given tiles: `[1 | 2]`, `[4 | 2]`, `[2 | 3]`, you could find the sequence `[1 | 2] [2 | 3] [4 | 2]`, which has only 1 mismatch between the last 2 tiles.

I've worked out a couple of algorithms for this. One finds the optimal (i.e. least number of mismatches) by calculating all permutations, calculating their *score*, and returning the best one. This can also be improved via DP or backtracking, for example avoiding branches of computation that already have a worse score than the current best solution. This works, but is obviously very slow for large test cases. I've also found ways to find a suboptimal solution but in reasonable time using things like Tabu search and genetic algorithms.

These work, but what I'm looking for is an **optimal** solution that will solve it faster than the O(N!) required by my initial brute-force solution.

I suspect however that this might not be possible. If you look at the problem as a graph problem, we have a graph in which tiles are vertices, and directed edges (directed since tiles cannot be rotated). It then becomes a problem of finding the shortest Hamiltonian path through the graph, which is NP-complete...

Is there another way to frame this such that it can be solved optimally in a reasonable time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like O(2^N * K) is feasible, since in a chain you don't really care what is inside.

You can use DP over 2^N*K array, where N is number of tiles (and 2^N is bitmask of tiles included) and K is last touching number.

Prototype for recursive function will look like that:

int solve(Bitmask mySet, int touchingNumber);

Here you loop over tiles in set (T), check if their last touchingNumber equals touchingNumber. Loop over last touching number (L). Now find minimum for all L and T:

- candidate for given T, L is solve(mySet-T, L), if T.first==L
- candidate for given T, L is solve(mySet-T, L)+1, if T.first!=L

Once calculated, solution for solve parameters is stored in global array and used for later calls.

It is possible to have no solution for given parameters, you should skip such results.

Final solution is minimum over all possible last touching numbers and full set of tiles.

Comment: What do you mean by `last touching number`?

Comment: Tile [1 | 3] has last touching number = 3. Tile sequence [1 | 2], [4 | 2] has last touching number=2

Comment: So what does it mean to "Loop over last touching number (L)"? Is L the set of the last touching numbers in T?

Comment: No, L is iteration variable. Value of L is one of possible last touching numbers, and in each recursion function L goes through all possible numbers.